# Do text level HTML elements get used for pronunciation in voice search results and with assistive technology?

Tags: html, accessibility, voice

I have searched online for advice on how to markup text of a technical nature so that it can work well for those using assistive technology. If I use voice search then that counts me in as using 'assistive technology'.

I am looking for answers concerning voice search as well as accessibility.

There is a lot of advice on using schema markup, e.g. JSON+LD and RDFa to get results in voice search, however, if I have text that has codes that need to be spelt out or even actual code, or even quotes and citations, I can't squeeze that into some microdata to get pronunciation cues over to some machine.

Before I get too far into my writing I would like to know if any text level elements get noticed, if they do then I can structure my content that bit better at the text level, e.g. using 'code', 'q', 'em', dfn', 'abbr'.